# GWT DateTimeFormat.parse always Illegal Argument Exception

Tags: parsing, gwt, date

Doesn't meter what string I pass to parse I'm always getting Illegal Argument exception on GWT DateTimeFormat.parse method.

For instance, what is wrong on the following code line:?

```
Date date = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("MM-dd-YYYY").parse("10-10-2012");
```

I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 10-10-2012
    at com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.DateTimeFormat.parse
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `YYYY` for the year in the format, you should use `yyyy`. The format you are specifiying would match a date that looks like: `10-10-YYYY` (since Y isn't a special date format character).